# Expressing a symmetry as a tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I am reading J-P. Serre's Complex Semisimple Lie Algebras, and have a question about some notation regarding expressing a symmetry as a tensor (I'm not sure if that's correct wording?). The following is at the beginning of chapter 5:

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $\alpha$ a nonzero element of $V$. One defines a *symmetry with vector $\alpha$* to be any automorphism $s$ of $V$ satisfying:

$i)\; s(\alpha) = -\alpha.$

$ii)$ *The set $H$ of elements of $V$ fixed by $s$ is a hyperplane of $V$.*

Let $V^*$ be the dual space of $V$, and let $\alpha^*$ be the unique element of $V^*$ which vanishes on $H$ and takes the value $2$ on $\alpha$. We have

$$s(x) = x - \langle \alpha^*, x \rangle \alpha \quad \forall x \in V,$$

which we can write as

$$s = 1 - \alpha^* \otimes \alpha$$

on identifying End$(V)$ with $V^* \otimes V$.

I am confused about how we are identifying End$(V)$ with $V^* \otimes V$. I see that if we have a symmetry $s \in$ End$(V)$, then we can uniquely identify that with an element of $V^* \otimes V$, as explained. I don't understand how this lets us identify all of End$(V)$ with $V^* \otimes V$.

I am also slightly unclear about writing $s = 1 - \alpha^* \otimes \alpha$. I don't see how $\langle \alpha^*, x \rangle \alpha$ could be written as $(\alpha^* \otimes \alpha)(x)$ (which it could be, if I am understanding correctly).

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a natural map $V^{\ast} \otimes V \to \text{End}(V)$ given by

$$f \otimes w \mapsto \left( v \mapsto f(v) w \right) \in \text{End}(V)$$

on pure tensors, and extending by linearity. This map is always injective; its image is precisely the endomorphisms $V \to V$ of finite rank, and hence it is surjective (so an isomorphism) iff $V$ is finite-dimensional. This isomorphism can be used, among other things, to define the trace in terms of the dual pairing.

More generally there is a natural map $V^{\ast} \otimes W \to \text{Hom}(V, W)$ defined the same as above, which is again always injective, whose image is again the maps of finite rank, and hence which is an isomorphism iff either $V$ or $W$ is finite-dimensional.